# JasperReport table column sum for page

Tags: jasper-reports

I need TO add a column sum to column footer of table object for each page.

If I create variable and set sum aggregation function than sum value appear for full report. But I need sum column data for each page, not for full report.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: NOTE: User need a solution for a jr:table component, subDataset where resetType="page" on variable can not be used.

Comment: I solve this problem by create subreport. I think it's one way. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** a solution for the **jr:table** component since it uses a **subdataset** where its not allowed to set `resetType="Page"`, but using a **subreport** it can be used.

I don't think there is a work around in components (jr:table,jr:list) using a subdataset but would be happy If someone can prove me wrong

**Solution using subreport**

On your **variable** set `resetType="Page"`

es.

```
<variable name="var" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Page" calculation="Sum"/>
....
</variable>
```

For more info on resetType see [JRVariable API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRVariable.html)

On your **textField** set `evaluationTime="Page"`

es.

```
<textField evaluationTime="Page">
 ....
</textField>
```

For more info on evaluationTime see [JRTextField API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRTextField.html)

Comment: I did try it. But if i set resetType="Page" for dataset variable i have compile error "Variable var of dataset cannot have Column or Page reset type".

Comment: aaii... thats true your are using a jr:table component... try this (i have no clue if it works, but probably its worth a try)... I have edit the answer... if it works I will improve the answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In case of Dataset set *resetType="Report"*